# Typescript: merge sequelize-typescipt's IFindOptions

Tags: typescript, merge, interface, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I want to extend IFindOptions of sequelize-typescipt.
Therefore I made the folliowing code:

```
declare module "sequelize-typescript" {
    interface IFindOptions<T> extends LoggingOptions, SearchPathOptions {
        lang?: string
    }
}
```

Now I try to call my model:

```
ExampleModel.findAll({lang: 'en'})
```

The linter in VS-Code does not throw an error but I can't compile because of the following error

```
Error TS2345: Argument of type '{ where: { process_definition_id: any; }; include: { model: typeof StepSuccessorDefinition; as: s...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IFindOptions<StepDefinition> | undefined'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'lang' does not exist in type 'IFindOptions<StepDefinition> | undefined'.
```

How can I make the code compile?